# Global variable resets when boolean

Tags: python

I was working on the LeetCode problem Graph Valid Tree (#261) and was having some weird issue with Python when using global variables to detect a cycle. Essentially, if I detected a cycle, I wanted to set `boolCycle` to `True`. However, sometimes, I would print `boolCycle` out during the DFS (where it would evaluate to `True`), and then after running DFS and it would evaluate to `False`. I couldn't figure out why this is happening as `boolCycle` is a global variable, and the only change I ever make to it is to set it to `True`, so it should remain that way.

I instead came up with a hacky solution where I just created a list called `cycle` and added an element to it if there was a cycle, which ended up working. I'm curious as to why modifying the global list works as intended but modifying the global boolean doesn't.

```
cycle = []
boolCycle = False
def dfs(parent, node):
    visited.add(node)
    for neighbor in graph[node]:
        if neighbor in visited and neighbor != parent:
            cycle.append('hello')
            boolCycle = True
            return
        if neighbor not in visited:
            dfs(node, neighbor)
```

Answer (score 1):

After

```
def dfs(parent, node):
```

add

```
    global boolCycle
```

Comment: Exactly.  Note that this is only needed because `boolCycle` is being **assigned to**, not merely accessed.  When you assign to a variable in a function, Python will assume that the variable is local unless you explicitly specify otherwise.